# In array is not work in if statement in javascript

Tags: jquery

When my `exist_id` array value is `null` the `if` condition works.

```
val = this.value  

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.all_id_checkbox').click(function() {
        var a = this.checked;
        if (a == true) {
            exist_id = new Array();
            exist_id = <?php echo json_encode($exist); ?>;
            val = parseInt(this.value);

            if (jQuery.inArray(val, exist_id)) { 
                exist_error.push(val);
            } else { }
        }   
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the value of `$exist`? Or better yet - what is your actual JS code after the PHP has been output? I'd guess that `exist_id` will be an object, hence `$.inArray` is not valid for use

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.all_id_checkbox').click(function() {
        var a = this.checked;
        var val = parseInt(this.value);  
        if (a == true) {
            var exist_error = [];
            var exist_id = <?php echo json_encode($exist); ?>;
            var new_array = Object.values(exist_id);
            if (jQuery.inArray(val, new_array)) { 
                exist_error.push(val);
            } else { }
        }   
    });
});`

Answer (score 0):

if `exist_id` is an object it is normal that `jQuery.inArray()` is not working; 
 inArray checking if an array of values contains a value so it can not make that check in key value pairs (json).

(You should start by showing us the output of `console.log(exist_id)`).

Anyways you are assigning the return of `json_encode()` to `exist_id` but as you may know JSON means "JavaScript Object Notation" so the return of `json_encode` will be in "object notation" hence when you assign it to `exist_id` it becomes a javascript object.

So obviously `jQuery.inArray` is not working.

In order for it to work just pass it the values of your object and not the json (key value pairs):

```
if (jQuery.inArray(val, Object.values(exist_id)))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/values

By the way, i see that you have a php tag in your javascript wich means that you are using inline scripts.This is a bad practice .What you should do is:

Put the data in a data attribute in a html element:

```
<div id="exist-id" data-ids="<?php echo json_encode($exist); ?>"></div>
```

then get the value in your external js script:

```
$('#exist_id').data('ids');
```

https://api.jquery.com/data/